# How to use result from SELECT query in another one

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I need to use selected rows in another query without selecting them again as subquery. Would be perfect if here possible to store them as variable.

What I mean:

```sql
/* First query: only one column returns (always), but multiple records, trying to store them as string */
SET @result := (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(target_field SEPARATOR ',')
FROM table_one
WHERE condition;

/* Second query: need to pass saved array into IN() condition */
SELECT *
FROM table_two
WHERE id IN(@result);
```

But suddenly it won't work because `@result` processed as *one* string value, not as array.

Is it possible to pass variable as array? Any alternative solution (except subqueries) allowed.

Comment: why not use subqueries?

Comment: select from t2 where col in (select column from t1...)

Comment: @Martin first query is time/load expensive 'cause processes large amount of records and aggregate them. Generally I exec few queries one-by-one, all based on result of first one, so using subqueries I should exec first query each time which is not optimal.

Comment: @Xeelley but it's more optimal than a broken query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT *
FROM table_two
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, @result);
```

Comment: Yeah, `find_in_set` is what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

you could just use a subquery in your where condition. This should be ok for [mySql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subqueries.html)

```
SELECT *
FROM table_two
WHERE id IN(SELECT id from table_one where condition_one);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but subquery usage is not accepted, sadly

Comment: How about a CTE? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html

Answer (score 1):

`JOIN` between tables can be used in this case:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_two
JOIN table_one ON table_two.id = table_one.target_field
WHERE table_one condition;
```

Comment: No. If we want to select from table_two where the ID exists in a subset of table_one, then `EXISTS` or `IN` is "the best way". With a join you might even have to apply `DISTINCT` in order to get rid of duplicates that you unnecessarily produced yourself.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, you right, fixed my answer. JOIN is not best but one of possible solutions

Comment: Yep, and as mentioned, depending on the data you may need `DISTINCT` here. It is quite likely, because it looks like the table_two.id can occur multiple times in table_one. Hence: `SELECT DISTINCT table_two.* FROM ...`.